# How do i make my Mouse over(hover)and on click events while the program is running

Tags: c#, arrays, onclick, mouseevent, mouseover

I have made a program where you ask the number of ellipses and it makes them in a different window in c#,but I want to have a mouse over effect-which I understood is called : MouseEnter and an onclick event,which I understood is called MouseDown, but I made an array of ellipses and I tried  the following :

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window2.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    int numOfElipses;
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        numOfElipses= MainWindow.numOfElipse;
        Ellipse[] ellipsePoints = new Ellipse[numOfElipses];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i=0;i<numOfElipses; i++)
        {
            SolidColorBrush brush =
                                new SolidColorBrush(
                                    Color.FromRgb(
                                    (byte)rnd.Next(255),
                                    (byte)rnd.Next(255),
                                    (byte)rnd.Next(255)
                                    ));
            var top = rnd.Next(0, 280);
            var left = rnd.Next(0, 450);
            ellipsePoints[i] = new Ellipse();
            ellipsePoints[i].Width = 40;
            ellipsePoints[i].Height = 40;
            Canvas.SetTop(ellipsePoints[i], i);
            Canvas.SetLeft(ellipsePoints[i], i*45);
            ellipsePoints[i].Fill = brush;
            c1.Children.Add(ellipsePoints[i]);
        }
    }
    private void E1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        Ellipse ellipsePoints = (Ellipse)sender;
        ellipsePoints.Fill = new 
        SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)r.Next(255), (byte)r.Next(255), 
        (byte)r.Next(255)));
    }
    private void E1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        c1.Children.Remove((Ellipse)sender);
    }

}
}
```

but it doesn't work.Can anyone explain why and how do I make it change color on a mouse over(hover) randomly,and disappear/be removed on a mouse click?
I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Doesn't work is a bit unclear. What does happen when you try to run this program?

Comment: Did you actually wire up the events? Just creating the methods won't do anything.

Comment: When I try to run it I can see the ellipses in different(random) colors like I did in the loop,but whenever I hover over one of the ellipses or click on them nothing happens.so the loop and everying works, just the event doesn't. maybe it doesn't recognize the object i'm on currently although I though the sender was supposed to take care of that.

Comment: What do you mean wire up the events?I'm a beginner so I don't know much about c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to actually hook up the events to the ellipses you are creating:

```
...
ellipsePoints[i].MouseEnter += E1_MouseEnter;    // "hook up" the Mouse Enter event
ellipsePoints[i].MouseDown += E1_MouseDown;      // "hook up" the Mouse Down event
c1.Children.Add(ellipsePoints[i]);
...
```

Simply creating the `E1_MouseEnter` and `E1_MouseDown` methods does not automatically wire them up, and that makes sense when we think about it. There could be any number of objects on the Window that have those events - how is the code supposed to know who should listen to?